# Sort by date in Jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, date, sorting, twig

Hi does anyone know how to sort by date in Jquery? I am using advanced custom fields and Twig for my code. Here it is:

```
    <section class="upcoming-events">
        <div class="customlayout">
            {% set intro_text = bloc.intro_text %}
            <h2>{{ intro_text.title }}</h2>
            {% for events in bloc.event %}
            {% for date in events.get_field('dates') %}
            {% set time = date.date %}
            {% set clock = date.time %}
            <h3>{{ events.title }}</h3>
            <h4>{{ time|e('wp_kses_post') }}</h4>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by date right inside Twig templates without Jquery:

```
{% set dates = [
    { day: '3/8/2013', },
    { day: '3/8/2019',},
    { day: '3/8/2018' },
] %}

{% for day in dates|sort((a,b) => a.day <=> b.day)|column('day') %}
    {{ day | date("m/d/Y")}}
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the output:

```
03/08/2013
03/08/2018
03/08/2019
```

Comment: Thank you! but how do i do this with the fields. I tried to paste the code and it broke the site.

Comment: {% for date in events.get_field('dates') %}
  {% set time = date.date %}
  {% set date = [
      { day: 'time' }
  ] %}

Comment: I tried this for my dates as I am trying to sort this automatically without having to manually input the dates